# How I can remove/add records from a pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

1. users
2. user_friends

`users` - id, username, email, etc..

`user_friends` - user_id, friend_id, for example

Relation in my User model:

```
public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
    }
```

How I can add friend or remove friend from a user? Do I need to create a new model for it?

**Add friend** -> add new record to `user_friends`

**Remove friend** --> Remove specific friend (record) from `user_friends`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$user->friend()->sync(['asd', 'asd1', 'asd2']);
```

OR deleting:

```
$user->friend()->detach();
```

Or adding new items:

```
$user->friend()->attach(['asd', 'asd1', 'asd2']);
```

Comment: What's different between sync and the others? and is it possible to check if the value exists before inserting a new one?

Comment: Sync removes all fried items and attaches what you give it to array. detach simply removes all or specific item and attach simply adds new item to object friends relation.

Comment: You can find a good documentation of that here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you! can you answer on the second question please - is it possible to check if the value exists before inserting a new one?

Comment: Yes of course you can: `$user->friends()->where('whatyouwanthere')->exists()` this function will return boolean true or false;